# Are $(1, 2, 1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3, 5, 3), (3, 8, 7, 13, 8), (1, 4, 6, 9, 7), (5, 13, 13, 25, 19)$ independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

We solve the system below for $c_i:$

$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 5 \\
        2 & 3 & 8 & 4 & 13 \\
        1 & 3 & 7 & 6 & 13 \\
        3 & 5 & 13 & 9 & 25 \\
        2 & 3 & 8 & 7 & 19 \\
        \end{bmatrix} $
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        c_1 \\
        c_2 \\
        c_3 \\
        c_4 \\
        c_5
        \end{bmatrix} = $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Echelon form of the augmented matrix is $
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix} $

Now my book says:

> The echelon form reveals that there are infinitely many solutions,
>   so the set of vectors is linearly dependent.

I am just trying to see if I understand the quoted bit correctly. The augmented matrix corresponds to five linear equations. Not counting the last two $0 = 0$, we have three equations in more than three unknowns implying infinite number of solutions. Since the solutions are made up of constants and there are infinite number of them, at least one of $c_i $ is not zero meaning the vectors are dependent. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The augmented matrix corresponds to five linear equations. Not
>   counting the last two $0=0$, we have three equations in more than
>   three unknowns implying infinite number of solutions.

Yes. Five variables and three equations, mean two free variables.

> Since the solutions are made up of constants and there are infinite 
>   number of

I do not get the "made up of constants" bit.

> them, at least one of $c_i$ is not zero meaning the vectors are
>   dependent. Does that make sense?

The two free variables can be set to non-zero values, so there exists a non-zero solution to the system. Linear independent vectors would only have the zero vector as solution.

Comment: "made up of constants" is "are constants". I was a bit apprehensive about the existence of some $c \neq 0$ just because it is in an infinite set. What you wrote makes everything crystal clear. Thanks.